# Error in Storing Session and to display Success message Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3, httpsession, session-storage

I followed the documentation on Laravel 5.3's HTTP Session https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session

Its not that to me in using this feature.

I created the sessions table via the laravel's documentation but Im not getting any stored sessions on the Application's - Seesion Storage.

Can someone shed some light on me? Thanks!

AdminController:

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
   $request->session()->put('key', 'value');
   $value = $request->session()->get('key');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are your actually trying to do here? The code you have posted will not display the session value in a browser if thats what you are trying to do.

If you just want to check if the session is working, you need to re-write the function like so:

```
   public function show(Request $request, $id)
   {
      $request->session()->put('key', 'value');
      return $request->session()->get('key');
   }
```

Comment: I want to store and retrieve user session in the "sessions" table created using the

"php artisan session:table"

Comment: Ok - so you can confirm you have a sessions table created? Have you got 'database' set as your driver in config/session.php

Comment: also, what makes you think you arent saving to the session? How are you verifying this?

Comment: Yes Ive set the driver to - database in config/session.php

By checking my database table sessions, there is no data that is being saved.

Comment: Do you have a .env file that has a SESSION_DRIVER variable? This will change the default value in config. What happens if you actually return a value from the session like my code above? What is displayed in the browser?

Comment: Yes Ive set the SESSION_DRIVER to database in the .env file.
Tried your code above and I didnt get anything...

Comment: Where should I check the supposed return result?

Comment: Just return the result to a webpage to check, or die dump it to the screen dd($request->session()->get('key'))

Answer (score 0):

You can override your ENVIRONMENT (.env) variables in `config/storage.php`; replace `env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')` for `database`. Also make sure to check whether your database settings are correct in either .env or `app/database.php`.